How can red LEDs still give a faint glow at a voltage of only 1.4V?
How can a red LED work at a voltage of only $1.4{\rm V}$? Red photons have an energy of $1.77{\rm V}$ if we use $\lambda = 0.7\mu\text{m}$ in the relation:
$$ E = \hbar \omega = \frac{2\pi\hbar c}{\lambda}  
 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  E[eV]  = \frac{2\pi\hbar c}{\lambda \,e}$$
Even if we assume they are at the edge of the [visible spectrum] at $750{\rm nm}$ that would still be $1.65{\rm V}$. If we assume the energy of each electron in the electric current is converted to photon energy when the electron annihilates with a hole, that would not work.

Is there extra energy added from the thermal motion? Wouldn't that violate thermodynamic principles?! Is there extra voltage from difference in work functions somewhere? But wouldn't that cancel out in a closed circuit?!
[To be precise: normal operating voltage for such a LED is higher, around $1.6\dots1.8 {\rm V}$, but you can easily see that there is still a faint glow at lower voltages than that, only vanishing if it is lowered to about $1.4 {\rm V}$.]

Which source did you get $1.4,\rm V$ from? The data here LED Physics - materials does not agree with this.

@Farcher Yes, the normal operating voltage is higher. I'll add that to the question! But the light output seems to follow the current and the current in a diode's $I!!-!!V$ characteristic does not drop to $0$ immediately below the nominal "forward voltage". There is still noticeable current (and light) down to about $1.4{\rm V}$.

I see now that the question is a duplicate. And answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/389960/283846 Notably, the answer confirms: "in some special conditions cooling of the device has been indeed observed."
